# Proof validation that a complex function is analytic

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

> Show that if $ f\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n} $ comverges on $ D(0,r) $, it defines an analytic function on $ D(0,r) $.

Where $ D(0,r) $ denotes the open disk with center at $0 $ and radius $ r $.

The definition of analytic function that I know is the following:

> given an open set $ U\subseteq\mathbb{C} $, we say that $ g:U\to\mathbb{C} $ is analytic, if for any $ z_0\in U $ the following holds: $$ g\upharpoonright_{D\left(z_{0},\delta\right)}\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}\left(z-z_{0}\right)^{n} $$
> For any $ z\in D\left(z_{0},\delta\right) $, and $ \delta $ is the maximum radius such that $ D\left(z_{0},\delta\right)\subset U $.

So based on this definition, here's what I've tried.

Fix some $z_0\in D(0,r) $. We need to prove that for any $ z\in D(z_0,\delta) $, $ f\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}\left(z-z_{0}\right)^{n} $, where $b_n $ is a complex sequence, and $ \delta $ is the maximum radius such that $ D(z_0,\delta) \subseteq D(0,r)$. that is $\delta =r-|z_0| $.

Now fix some $ z_1 \in D(z_0,\delta)$. We'll show that $ f\left(z_{1}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}\left(z_{1}-z_{0}\right)^{n} $.

Since $z_1\in D(z_0,\delta)$, also $z_1 \in D(z_0,\delta )$. So there exist $ R<r $ such that $ z_{0}\in D\left(0,R\right) $ and also $ z_{1}\in D\left(0,R\right) $. And since $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n} $ converges on $ D(0,r) $, also as a power series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n} $ converge uniformly on $ \overline{D\left(0,R\right)} $ (the closed disk). Thus, $ f(z) $ is continuously differentiable infinitly many times, and:

$$ f^{(k)}(z_{0})=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(j+k\right)a_{j+k}z_{0}^{j} $$

So we can write $ f(z) $ as its taylor polynomial around $z_0 $ + the reminder in the form of Lagrange;

$$ f\left(z\right)=P_{k,z_{0}}\left(z\right)+R_{k+1}\left(z\right) $$

This equality holds for any $ z\in\overline{D\left(0,R\right)} $ and in particular for $ z_1 $. That is $$ f\left(z_{1}\right)=P_{k,z_{0}}\left(z_{1}\right)+R_{k+1}\left(z_{1}\right) $$

Now note that $ |R_{k+1}\left(z_{1}\right)|=|\frac{f^{(k+1)}\left(\tilde{z}\right)}{\left(k+1\right)!}\left(z-z_{0}\right)^{k+1}| $

Where $ \tilde{z}\in D\left(z_{0},d\left(z_{0},z\right)\right) $ and so $ |\tilde{z}|\leq R $ so $$ |R_{k+1}\left(z_{1}\right)|\leq\frac{|z-z_{0}|^{k+1}}{\left(k+1\right)!}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|\left(j+k+1\right)a_{j+k+1}||R|^{j}\right) $$

Note that $ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|\left(j+k+1\right)a_{j+k+1}||R|^{j} $ converge, and so we can denote it as $ M $ and treat it as a constant. That is $$ |R_{k+1}\left(z_{1}\right)|\leq M\frac{|z_{1}-z_{0}|^{k+1}}{\left(k+1\right)!}\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

By the quotient test.

All in all $$ f\left(z_{1}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{f^{(n)}\left(z_{0}\right)}{n!}\left(z_{1}-z_{0}\right)^{n}+R_{k+1}\left(z_{1}\right) $$

$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}f\left(z_{1}\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{f^{(n)}\left(z_{0}\right)}{n!}\left(z_{1}-z_{0}\right)^{n}+\lim_{k\to\infty}R_{k+1}\left(z_{1}\right) $$

And so $ f\left(z_{1}\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{f^{(n)}\left(z_{0}\right)}{n!}\left(z_{1}-z_{0}\right)^{n}$

For any $z_1\in D(z_0,\delta ) $ and so by definition $ f $ is analytic on $D(0,r) $.

Is this proof legit?

Thanks in advance.